Definition of carrier map/ task for two processes
In distributed computing, we define a carrier map to be a map between a graph $\mathcal{G}$ and the power set $2^\mathcal{H}$ of a graph $\mathcal{H}$ s.t, for simplices $\sigma$ and $\tau$ of $\mathcal{G}$
$$\sigma \subseteq \tau \implies \Phi(\sigma) \subseteq \Phi(\tau).$$
Then in the definition of a task, there is a name-preserving carrier map between a pure chromatic input graph of dimension 1 and a pure chromatique output graph of dimension 1. Finally, it says that all of this implies that if the name-preserving carrier map starts on two vertices ($A$ and $B$) that form an edge, then there is an output configuration, where the outputs of those vertices also form an edge. I have two questions:

First: why has the definition of a carrier map in the definition of task change? It now goes from a graph to a graph, instead of from a graph to the power set of a graph.
Second: I don't see the last implication: rigidity (included in name-preserving) implies that a vertex can be sent to a subset of vertices and an edge to a pure graph of dimension 1. So theoretically we could have something like: $A$ is sent to a vertex, $B$ is sent to another vertex, those vertices are part of some edges, but there is no need for the images of $A$ and $B$ to be connected by an edge (for example if the egde formed by $A$ and $B$ is sent to a pure graph of dimension 1, which is not connected).. What am I missing?

Thanks
